# How to update some but not all fields in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

here is the UserSchema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, index:{unique: true} },
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    lastName: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, index:{unique: true} }, 
    password: { type: String, required: true, select: false }
});
```

Here is the http PUT request:

```
  // update user information
  api.put('/users/:username', function(req, res) {

    User.findOne({username: req.params.username}, function(err, user) {

      if (err){
        res.send(err);
        return;
      }

      if (!user){
        res.status(404).send({
          success: false,
          message: "user not found"
        });
      } else {
        user.username = req.body.username;
        user.email = req.body.email;
        user.password = req.body.password;
        user.firstName = req.body.firstName;
        user.lastName = req.body.lastName;

        user.save(function(err) {
          if (err){
            res.send(err);
            return;
          }

          res.json({
            success: true,
            message: "user information updated."
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

The question is, if the user only want to update limited fields, for example, only update username, then the above code does not work, the error looks like this:

```
{
  "message": "User validation failed",
  "name": "ValidationError",
  "errors": {
    "lastName": {
      "properties": {
        "type": "required",
        "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
        "path": "lastName"
      },
      "message": "Path `lastName` is required.",
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "lastName"
    },
    "firstName": {
      "properties": {
        "type": "required",
        "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
        "path": "firstName"
      },
.........
```

so how can I implemement to allow user updates some but not all fields?

Any comments and suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ['findOneAndUpdate'](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) method.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({username: req.params.username}, {username: req.body.username}, function(err, user) {
  //...
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Jason Cust, I think I have some problems to understand `findOneAndUpdate(...)`, the snippet you provided is only able to change the username, am I right? What if I do not know what field the user want to update? thanks.

Comment: You *could* pass the raw post body as the update object but would you really want to do that? What if you only want certain fields to be updated? You can inspect the body to see what's present and allow only the fields that are okay to be updated to be included in the update object.

Comment: @PrathameshMore Can you expand on your comment?

Answer (score 9):

Using [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) with the operator [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) in the update object:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({username: req.params.username}, { $set: req.body }, { new: true }, callback);
```

`$set` will allow you to modify only the supplied fields in the `req.body` object.

Comment: Without assuming that `req.body` has been sanitized or that the model has adequate validation rules, this could be a very bad pattern. While yes, it would update the supplied fields in `req.body`, you have no control over what fields those are. Any update could update any field without the above noted validations of sanitization.

Comment: @JasonCust your solution above doesn't work at all though

Answer (score 5):

I ended up using this solution:

```js
const dot = require('dot-object'); // this package works like magic

const updateData = { some: true, fields: true };

User.updateOne(
  { _id: req.user._id },
  { $set: dot.dot(updateData) },
  (err, results) => {
    if (err) res.json({ err: true });
    else res.json({ success: true });
  }
);
```

I found this idea here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5285#issuecomment-439378282

Answer (score 4):

This is a good compromise:

Specify the fields that the user can update

```
let fieldToUpdate = {
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
  };
```

Then delete all the keys that contains falsy value

```
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(fieldToUpdate)) {
    if (!value) {
      delete fieldToUpdate[key];
    }
  }
```

Then Update the value using the $set operator

```
const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.user.id,
    { $set: { ...fieldToUpdate } },
    {
      runValidators: true,
      new: true,
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand is that you want to be able to update any amount of fields. The code below is from a past project.

Model

```
const ingredientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: { type:String, required: true },   
    quantity: { type: Number, default: 0}
});
```

HTTP PUT

```
router.put('/:ingredientId', (req, res, next) => {
    // extracting ingredient id from url parameters
    const id = req.params.ingredientId;

    //creating a map from the passed array
    const updateOps = {};
    for(const ops of req.body){
        updateOps[ops.propName] = ops.value;
    }

    //updating the found ingredient with the new map
    Ingredient.update({_id: id}, { $set: updateOps})
        .exec()
        .then(result =>{
            console.log(result);
            //returning successful operation information
            res.status(200).json(result);
        })
        //catching any errors that might have occured from above operation
        .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
            //returning server error
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
});
```

PUT Request (json)

```
[
    {"propName": "name", "value": "Some other name"},
    {"propName": "quantity", "value": "15"},
]
```

or if you one want to update one field

```
[
    {"propName": "name", "value": "Some other name"}
]
```

basically you have an array of these property/field names and their new values. you can update just one or all of them this way if you would like. Or none of them I believe.

Hopefully, this helps! if you have any questions just ask!