# ValidationError when sending updated data in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a problem when updating the data of the object "product" and I get this error in the console. When sending updated data, the service shuts down and I get this error. Tell me what code you need and I will provide it to you. Thank you.

```
C:\compra-express\back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2782
    this.$__.validationError = new ValidationError(this);
                               ^

ValidationError: producto validation failed: portada: Path `portada` is required., slug: Path `slug` is required.
    at Document.invalidate (C:\compra-express\back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2782:32)
    at C:\compra-express\back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2574:17
    at C:\compra-express\back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1273:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
  errors: {
    portada: ValidatorError: Path `portada` is required.
        at validate (C:\compra-express\back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1270:13)
        at C:\compra-express\back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1253:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at SchemaType.doValidate (C:\compra-express\back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1198:14)
        at C:\compra-express\back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2567:18
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
      properties: {
        validator: [Function (anonymous)],
        message: 'Path `portada` is required.',
        type: 'required',
        path: 'portada',
        value: undefined
      },
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'portada',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    },
    slug: ValidatorError: Path `slug` is required.
        at validate (C:\compra-express\back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1270:13)
        at C:\compra-express\back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1253:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at SchemaType.doValidate (C:\compra-express\back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1198:14)
        at C:\compra-express\back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2567:18
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
      properties: {
        validator: [Function (anonymous)],
        message: 'Path `slug` is required.',
        type: 'required',
        path: 'slug',
        value: undefined
      },
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'slug',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
  },
  _message: 'producto validation failed'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The model of the product object is this:

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose'); //variable per a mongoose
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;   //inicialitza l'esquema de mongoose

//--MODEL DE PRODUCTO--//
var ProductoSchema = Schema({   //Variable per a que desi tot Schema | Conté tots els camps de la col·lecció
    titulo: {type: String, required: true}, //Assignem el tipus de dada i fem que sigui un camp requerit/obligatori
    slug: {type: String, required: true},
    galeria: [{type: Object, required: false}],    //Array
    portada: {type: String, required: true},
    precio: {type: Number, required: true},
    descripcion: {type: String, required: true},
    contenido: {type: String, required: true},
    stock: {type: Number, required: true},
    nventas: {type: Number, default: 0, required: true},
    npuntos: {type: Number, default: 0, required: true},
    categoria: {type: String, required: true},
    estado: {type:String, default: 'Edicion', required: true},
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now, require: true}
});

//Exportem el model
module.exports = mongoose.model('producto', ProductoSchema);   //Rep el nom d'aquest schema i el nostre Schema
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors are telling you that the values for both portada and slug are undefined even though they are required. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55474271/20174961